# How to schedule a periodic job that ends after given condition is true?

Tags: scala, akka

I looked at [akka scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.4/#akka.actor.Scheduler) and the [example here](https://gist.github.com/oniltonmaciel/6725726) that allows me to schedule periodic and single tasks. I need to make a method with the following signature:

```
def doWhile(fn: => Unit, whileFn: => Boolean, period:Long) = {
  // while whileFn evaluates to true, repeat fn every period millisecs
}
```

I can wrap `fn` inside another method `fnNew` that evaluates `whileFn` and executes `fn` if true. I can then schedule `fnNew` to be executed regularly. But this seems to be a poor hack. I would like `fnNew` to be "unscheduled" the moment `whileFn` evaluates to false. What is the right way to do it?

Edit: I want to avoid using explicit actors and want to avoid using a shared state as in the following code:

```
def doRegularly(fn: => Unit, periodMillis:Long) = 
    scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, periodMillis milliseconds)(fn)
def doWhile(fn: => Unit, whileFn: => Boolean, period:Long) = {
  var c:Option[Cancellable] = None
  c = Some(doRegularly(
            if (whileFn) fn 
            else {
               if (c.isDefined)  c.get.cancel
            }, period))
}
```

(which has the shared value `c`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can leverage `scheduleOnce` to accomplish what you want w/o having shared state in the definition of `doWhile`.  If you defined `doWhile` like so:

```
def doWhile(fn: => Unit, whileFn: => Boolean, duration:FiniteDuration)(implicit sys:ActorSystem) {
  if (whileFn){
    fn
    sys.scheduler.scheduleOnce(duration)(doWhile(fn, whileFn, duration))(sys.dispatcher)
  }
}
```

Then you could, for example, invoke it with the following piece of code:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("SchedTest")        
var count = 1
doWhile(printAndInc, count <= 10, 1 second)

def printAndInc{
  println(s"count is $count")
  count += 1
}
```

If you run the above code, you will see it print the numbers 1 to 10 with a second pause between.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/scheduler.html), you can use `cancel`

```
//This will schedule to send the Tick-message
//to the tickActor after 0ms repeating every 50ms
val cancellable =
  system.scheduler.schedule(0 milliseconds,
    50 milliseconds,
    tickActor,
    Tick)
```

//This cancels further Ticks to be sent
cancellable.cancel()

`schedule` method returns an object of type `Cancellable` which has the cancel method.
I am not sure, how you are planning to use `whileFn` but whenever it returns false, call the cancel method on the `Cancellable` object.

Comment: I will have to use some shared state between the two methods which is what I am trying to avoid